# Qual a diferença entre "Exception.Message" e "Exception.ToString()"?

Tags: c#, .net, string, exceção

Eu já li algumas resposta a respeito do `try-catch` e sobre as `Exception`s, mas eu ainda tenho duvida sobre a diferença em `Exception.Message` e `Exception.ToString()`:

- Qual a diferença entre uma e outra?
- Qual devo apresentar para o usuário?
- Qual devo gravar em um banco de *logs* de erro por exemplo?

Comment: Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176707/exception-message-vs-exception-tostring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ex.Message

Apresenta apenas a mensagem básica do erro de forma bem simples.

> ex.ToString()?

Apresenta muito mais informação, ali tem tudo o que é importante, incluindo *stack trace* e exceções internas (*inner exception*) à exceção sendo observada, além da própria `Message`. Dados dependentes de cultura são apresentados na cultura atual do sistema.

> Qual devo apresentar para o usuário?

Qual achar melhor para o contexto.

Eu diria para evitar o `.ToString()`. Acho ela melhor para outras funções. Ela pode ser útil em depuração, eventualmente um *log* detalhado em desenvolvimento. Ela não ajuda muito o usuário. É um erro que quase todo mundo comete.

Mesmo a mensagem simples talvez não devesse ser apresentada diretamente. Até existem casos para fazer isso, mas na maior parte das vezes produzirá uma experiência melhor para o usuário se tratar de forma mais personalizada ainda para cada caso.

Se tiver um mecanismo centralizado de auxílio à exceções é bem fácil tratar os tipos mais comum mais personalizadamente ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001508/221800)). E as exceções criadas para aquele sistema podem ser feitas pensando em uma forma melhor.

Montar uma mensagem usando as várias informações disponíveis no objeto da exceção dará o melhor resultado. Usar algo já montado (`.ToString()`) é o mais fácil a fazer.

> Qual devo gravar em um banco de logs de erro por exemplo?

Não sei se alguma deva ser gravada diretamente. Em um *log* simples e estruturado ambas podem atrapalhar. Em um *log* que deseje mais informação a mensagem pode ajudar detectar o problema. Apenas em um *log* mais detalhado é interessante *logar* o resultado do `.ToString()`. Acho que esse tipo de *log* só costuma ser útil enquanto está desenvolvendo a aplicação. Em produção pode ser um exagero produzir essa massa de informação.

Claro que depende um pouco de objetivo e até gosto, de acordo com o fluxo que prefere trabalhar. Não existe certo ou errado nisso.

## Conclusão

Só não capture exceções em excesso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado.